# Turning strings into datetime in python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x

Im new in Python and Ive got this problem:
I want to convert this string and turn it into a datetime:
str = "06/04/2015"  ------> data = datetime(2015,04,06)

The problem is that I will use the solution to turn other strings into data, like "12/02/2015", but in the month number the first index is a zero and I will use only the number two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert strings to datetime objects using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function, where the first argument is the string you want to convert to a datetime object, and the 2nd object is the format the date is represented in.

example:

```
import datetime
my_datestr = "06/04/2015"
my_dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_datestr, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) in the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library, present in the [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module. It serves to do exactly what you require.

Here's the exact code that you would need:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('06/04/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```